# Why do I get an "invalid date" error for %-m%d%Y"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

Can someone explain why I'm getting an invalid date error with the following line?

```
Date.strptime("3082013",'%-m%d%Y')
```

From my understanding, `%-m` should look for a month with no leading `0`.  However, executing this code returns

```
ArgumentError: invalid date
```

Assuming I can't change the format of the incoming date, what is the best way to deal with this situation?

Comment: What should be the resulting date of 1112013 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a zero to the left :

```
Date.strptime("3082013".rjust(8,'0'),'%-m%d%Y')
```

Comment: the second parameter should be `%m%d%Y` :)

Comment: Ohh that's way smarter than the way I was going to go about this.  I was sitting down to write a regex, this is much nicer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `strptime` does not suppor the minus (-) flag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some sort of separator between your month/day/year. Otherwise how will Ruby know whether "3082013" is 3/08/2013 or 30/8/2013?

Comment: It would know if strptime supported %-m, which goes from 1..12

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to get a bit lower-level, and do what `Date.strptime` would do for you:

```
"3082013".scan(/(\d+) (\d{2}) (\d{4})/x).first
=> ["3", "08", "2013"]
```

If `"308213"` is in `MMDDYYYY` format:

```
mon, day, year = "03082013".scan(/(\d+) (\d{2}) (\d{4})/x).first.map(&:to_i)
=> [3, 8, 2013]
```

Or, if you know that it's in `DDMMYYYY` format, switch `mon` and `day`:

```
day, mon, year = "03082013".scan(/(\d+) (\d{2}) (\d{4})/x).first.map(&:to_i)
=> [3, 8, 2013]
```

Then you can create a Date object:

```
Date.new(year, mon, day)
=> #<Date: 2013-03-08 ((2456360j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```